# scanf is overwriting a second variable

Tags: c, scanf

I'm asking the user to type in two variables. First an unsigned integer `a` and second an unsigned character `b`. The reading in of `a` works fine, but after reading in `b`, `a` is 0.

I found out that the pointer to `a` is one greater than the pointer to `b`. I realized that when `b` is greater than 255 `a` is not 0 anymore. So it seem to me that `scanf` reads in more than one byte for `b` and overwrites `a`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned char b;

    printf("a: ");
    scanf("%u", &a); /* 255 */
    printf("b: ");
    scanf("%hhu", &b); /* 17 */

    printf("a: %u\n", a); /* a: 0 */
    printf("b: %u\n", b); /* b: 17 */

    printf("pointer a: %u\n", &a); /* pointer a: 6422316 */
    printf("pointer b: %u\n", &b); /* pointer b: 6422315 */

    return 0;
}
```

Since I'm new to programming in C, I'm not sure what information is necessary to understand my problem. I'm using a 64 bit processor an this is the used compiler:

```
gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-8.2.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --target=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --with-arch=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-3' --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-isl=/mingw --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls --disable-build-format-warnings
Thread model: win32
gcc version 8.2.0 (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-3)
```

Comment: Nitpick: `printf("pointer a: %u\n", &a);` should better be `printf("pointer a: %p\n", (void*)&a);`, same as `b` also.

Comment: What if you print `a` right after scanning it? Before scanning `b`.

Comment: @WeatherVane wrong line. `unsigned char` is also promoted to `int` on the other`, they're compatible

Comment: Yeah I just notice thanks. I misread that for the `scanf`.

Comment: Can't reproduce https://ideone.com/dsw2I6 Show the whole I/O session

Comment: The code is correct, besides the `%u` used to print a format but the behaviour is akin to expected undefined behaviour given the layout *and* format `%u` to read in the unsigned char...

Comment: Cannot reproduce this error.

Comment: Since you're using MingW, is there a chance that it is using the MS C runtime library, and that does not support `%hhu`?  Have you checked the return values from `scanf()`?

Comment: Does MinGW's C runtime implement `%hhu` correctly? I would wonder if maybe it's being treated as equivalent to `%u` and therefore clobbering memory beyond the limits of `b`.

Comment: @zwol MinGW's C runtime library does not implement `%hhu` properly. It's a GNU extension. If `b` was declared as an `unsigned short` and `%hu` was used, this would work properly.

Comment: @JL2210 `hh` is not GNU extension http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p11

Comment: @EugeneSh. Windows does not implement C11. It only went so far as to implement some parts of C99.

Comment: @Kaniee What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @JL2210 This is not C11, it is there since C99 at the very least http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.19.6.2p11. And it is definitely not GNU extension. But yes, I could reproduce it on mingw64 gcc, so I would take the possibility that windows-specific C library is not implementing it properly.

Comment: @EugeneSh. "It only went so far as to implement *some parts of C99*."

Comment: @EugeneSh. et al Indeed, I distinctly recalled the additional `scanf` features being one of the aspects of C99 that MSVCRT.DLL did _not_ implement.

Comment: The MSVC6.0 was notoriously bad. It got the for loop scoping completely wrong, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
    scanf("%hhu", &b); /* 17 */
```

Microsoft's C runtime library does not implement `%hhu` (it was not part of the C standard prior to C99). This causes the input to be interpreted as a `short` (due to how MSVCRT interprets `hh` as `h` in the format specifier), and writes past the limits of `b` and overwrites parts of `a`.

To fix this problem, change the type of `a` to `unsigned short` and use `%hu` as the format specifier OR pass the `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` flag to your compiler.

Comment: More precisely yet, MinGW uses `MSVCRT.DLL`, which is the only C runtime library that actually ships with Windows (which is why they use it) but which Microsoft has intentionally not updated in many years and would really rather new applications _not_ use.  I was under the impression that MinGW64 was working on changing this, but I could be wrong and/or out of date.

Comment: (Microsoft deserves a good deal of blame for not implementing C99 in their compilers _in general_ until more than a decade later, but MinGW shares some of the blame for use of `MSVCRT.DLL` in particular.)

Comment: @JL2210 thanks for the explanation. What does this flag do `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO`?

Comment: @Kaniee It enables MinGW's ANSI-compliant stdio implementation.

Answer (score 4):

This is a near duplicate of various questions about printing the value of `size_t` with `%zu` in code compiled with MinGW. Both `z` and `hh` length modifiers appeared in C99.

The C89 described the length modifiers as follows

> - An optional `h`, `l` (ell) or `L` indicating the size of the receiving object. The conversion specifiers `d`, `i`, and `n` shall be preceded by `h` if the corresponding argument is a pointer to `short int` rather than a pointer to `int`, or by `l` if it is a pointer to `long int`. Similarly, the conversion specifiers `o`, `u`, and `x` shall be preceded by `h` if the corresponding argument is a pointer to `unsigned short int` rather than a pointer to `unsigned int`, or by `l` if it is a pointer to `unsigned long int`. Finally, the conversion specifiers `e`, `f`, and `g` shall be preceded by K if the corresponding argument is a pointer to `double` rather than a pointer to `float`, or by `L` if it is a pointer to `long` double . If an `h`, `l`, or `L` appears with any other conversion specifier, the behavior is undefined.

The `hh` length modifier appeared in C99.  [C11 7.21.6.1p7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p7) says:

> **`hh`**
>
> Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a signed char or unsigned char argument (the argument will have been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be converted to signed char or unsigned char before printing); or that a following `n` conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a signed char argument.

MinGW uses the MSVCRT.DLL as the C library - this library supports *only* C89. Upon seeing the `%hhu` the behaviour is *undefined* according to C89, but it is consistent with interpreting that as `%hu` and writing an `unsigned short` value at the *2* bytes starting from `&a`.

---

The solution is to read the value into a temporary `unsigned short` or `unsigned int` and then assign that to the `unsigned char`.